# Which episode explains the meaning of the symbols on the palm of the hands?

Tags: naruto

[image: screenshot of the scene]

From opening 16, what do these symbols mean and which episode exactly is it from?

Comment: I know that together they make the kanji meaning love.

Answer (score 9):

The symbols can be found on an old man called [Bunpuku](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Bunpuku)'s both palms. He was the former Jinchūriki of Sunagakure.

*Watch Naruto Shippūden episode 392*

[image]

> In his *left palm*, the kanji [[受]{うける} (U-ke-ru)](http://jisho.org/search/%23kanji%20%E5%8F%97) means **accept** and **receive**.
>   In his *right palm*, the kanji [[心]{こころ} (Ko-ko-ro)](http://jisho.org/search/%23kanji%20%E5%BF%83) means **heart** and **mind**.

Together with two palms, it forms the kanji [[愛]{いとしい} (I-to-shi)](http://jisho.org/search/%23kanji%20%E6%84%9B) which means **love** and **affection**.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remember Gaara's tattoo on his forehead. If both symbols are combined, it forms 愛 (*ai*) symbol, which means "love".

Comment: 1) the kanji on the left doesn't look like 愛 as it's missing some strokes, note the gap. 2) this answer falls short in answering the question entirely by not answering the other symbol means

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer since you're not answering the question completely.

Answer (score 0):

On the left hand, it’s a kanji (chinese character) ‘receipt’ ; on the right hand, it’s a reversed kanji ‘heart’.  When you put both hands together, these two kanjis form another kanji ‘Love’.  Indeed, love is the feeling received by the heart.  You got to have the heart in order to feel love.